# multiple variables delegated by project gradle.properties

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have many variables in my gradle.properties file that I would like to access from my gradle.build.kts.

Currently I am using the following approach

```
val project1Version by project
val project2Version by project
val project3Version by project
val project4Version by project
val project5Version by project
val project6Version by project
```

My gradle.properties file consists of a key valye pairs like

```
project1Version=1.2.0
```

I would like to know if there is a more clean syntax to intialize all the variables in my build script.

Thanks

Comment: What do you think about using [`libs.versions.toml`](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/platforms.html#sub:conventional-dependencies-toml) instead of storing the versions in `gradle.properties`? Then Gradle will generate some nice DSL accessors.